# Correction for serial voting not received yet

Tags: support, bug, reputation, serial-voting

I got my reputation back for the questions marked with green marker, but not for the questions marked with red color.

**This is not a duplicate.**

I saw that link before. I didn't get my reputation back.

[image]

Comment: I upvoted this post because I think the downvote is unfair. The OP did get massive serial downvotes and did not get them corrected in a timely manner. He did not understand why, so he asked the question. I thought this site is for this kind of questions, am I wrong? BTW, I also upvoted the answer because I think it provides the explanation which I learned something myself.

Comment: The FAQ [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) says what to do if 24 hours have passed since serial voting took place and the votes have not been reversed.

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of questions tagged [tag:faq] if the answer to that question also addresses this question, even though the questions themselves may not be exactly the same. This is to link users to the canonical posts regarding topics. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Comment: I got suspended :( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330229/i-am-a-victim-of-serial-voting-so-i-reported-it-to-moderators-and-got-suspended

Comment: You need to explain *why* your question is not a duplicate, it's not enough to say you read a post or not all your rep was restituted.

Comment: Judging from that post, I'm assuming you used a second account to serially downvote your posts, just to test if they would be reversed by the system?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog Your comment is a serious accusation. I am wondering what kind of evidence do you have? And why would somebody do that? (serial downvote one's own posts?) If he did that, what if the system did not catch it? He lost reps for nothing. If the system did catch it and find out the sock puppet was indeed himself, he'll probably get suspended. One way or the other, he would be a loser. So, why would somebody do such a silly thing?

Comment: @scaaahu I can think of one nefarious purpose: to determine when and when not the serial voting script kicks in, so that one can know exactly how to serial-vote to evade the script. But I think that this was probably just an innocent test, just to test out the feature.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog I don't have a second account !!

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog I got +20 points saying that the user is removed

Answer (score 1):

The reversal you mention happened at 03:00 UTC that day, and reversed the serial votes from the previous day. Then, the three serial votes you highlighted happened later, at 09:17-09:18 UTC that day.

The serial voting script runs [once a day at 03:00 UTC](/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). Since the serial votes you mention happened *after* that time that day, they'll be detected by the next day's script. There's no bug here; the system is working as intended.

Comment: But still I didn't get those back even in the next day

Comment: But those last three happened 4 days ago so no future script is still going to catch them. I assume that's why OP is asking

Comment: @n8te In that case, this is answered in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me): "if 24 hours have passed and the serial votes have not been reversed, flag one of your posts for moderator attention".

Comment: Yeah, was just pointing it out so you could update your answer to address OP's specific case. I imagine 3 downvotes by the same user in a day is just under the threshold that the script checks for

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog Ok I will flag

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog See here : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330229/i-am-a-victim-of-serial-voting-so-i-reported-it-to-moderators-and-got-suspended